# Mapping abstract classes with includePaths

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a question regarding mapping of Hibernate Search and using an abstract base class.
I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Found invalid @IndexedEmbedded->paths configured on class nl.project.model.social.AbstractGroup, member language: language.id
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.validateAllPathsEncountered(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:901)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.checkForIndexedEmbedded(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeMemberLevelAnnotations(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeClass(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.<init>(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderContainedEntity.<init>(DocumentBuilderContainedEntity.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
```

Based on the following mapping configuration

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 3)
@Indexed
public abstract class AbstractGroup implements Serializable, IEntity, IPhoto{

    protected Language language;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_LanguageId")
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,region=CacheRegion.NEVERCHANGE)
    @NotNull
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths={"id"})
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "GRP")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,region=CacheRegion.GROUP)
public class Group extends AbstractGroup{

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PGE")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,region=CacheRegion.GROUP)
public class Page extends AbstractGroup{
```

I've tried putting @Indexed on the subclass but this gives the same error.

Comment: BTW, Adding @Indexed to both child classes and removing abstract from the superclass and adding a discriminatorcolumn there resolves the issue, but AFAIC that seems like a workaround more than "the correct approach"

Answer (score 1):

The *@Indexed* annotation should indeed be on the sub classes. However, I am not sure what this should have to to with te discriminator column. JPA and Search annotations should be orthogonal. Two different things really. Btw, how does your *Language* entity look like? See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=993097&hilit=abstract+base+class